# Can I create an unauthenticated user for a Community?

Tags: community, customer-community

I'm trying to create a public community to allow read only access to certain knowledge articles and read/create access for cases. I've tried editing the Community Profile with no luck. I've made all tabs visible to the profile and created an app for the tabs and made it the default for the profile and made sure the tabs are availalbe on the community site. When I go to the URL it is still requiring me to login. Is it possible to create an unauthenticated user profile for a Community Site or what else do I need to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Salesfoce Communities are intended for authenticated user only.

If you want to create a public presence, you may expose content using

- Force.com Sites
- Site.com

Here is a link describing differences:
http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000066945&language=en_US